# Finding the mean of a variable within an imputed data set for population quintiles

Tags: r

I have a data set "base_data" which has missing values. I have therefore used the package 'Amelia' to impute the missing values into an object "a.output".

I have been able to find the mean for some variables within the imputed results using the following code:

```
q.out<-NULL
se.out<-NULL
for(i in 1:m) {   
dclus <- svydesign(id=~site, data=a.output$base_data[[i]]) 

q.out <- rbind(q.out, coef(svymean(~hh_expenditure, dclus)))
se.out <- rbind(se.out, SE(svymean(~hh_expenditure, dclus)))}
```

I have combined the results using:

```
svymean.combine <- mi.meld(q = q.out, se = se.out)
```

Which gives me the mean and standard error for household expenditure (hh_expenditure) across the population.

However I have a variable which splits the population into wealth quintiles (wealth_quin).

As such, I am now wanting to find the average, and standard error, of the household expenditure per wealth_quin (a variable which is either 1,2,3,4,or 5).

I initially tried subsetting the imputed data, but this came up with many errors.

Is there a way to do this without having to split up the data into the 5 wealth quintiles before imputing the data?

Cheers,

Timothy

EDIT: HERE IS A WORKABLE EXAMPLE

```
require(Amelia)
require(survey)
a<-as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16))
b<-as.data.frame(c(1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2))
c<-as.data.frame(c(2,7,8,5,4,4,3,8,7,9,10,1,3,3,2,8))
d<-as.data.frame(c(3,9,7,4,5,5,2,10,8,10,12,2,4,4,3,7))
e<-as.data.frame(c(2500,8000,NA,4500,4500,NA,2500,NA,7400,9648,1112,1532,3487,3544,NA,7000)

impute<-cbind(a,b,c,d,e)
names(impute) <- c("X","site","var2","var3", "hh_inc")
```

so no we have a data frame to work with, with missing values for hh_inc which I want to impute.
first step, set the number of imputations

```
m<-5
```

now run the imputation:

```
a.output <- amelia(x = impute, m=m, autopri=0.5,cs="X",
               idvars=c("site","var2"),
               logs=c("hh_inc","var3"))
```

a.output is now holds the data from the 5 imputations.

What I now want to do is find the average (and standard error) hh_inc for site 1 and site 2 separately using the imputed values from amelia.

How is that possible to do? I know it is possible to do if I just ignore the NA's. But this might introduce bias, hence why I imputed the values in the first place.

Cheers,

Timothy

EDIT:
I have placed a bounty to this. If no one knows the exact way to do it, then the results from the individual imputed data sets can be combined using Rubins formula (http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~jls/mifaq.html#minf)
As such, I will award to bounty to someone who can transform the 5 separate imputed datasets from the Amelia object into 5 separate, complete, data frames.

Comment: The probability of getting an answer will increase if you provide a *reproducible* example.

Comment: @svenhohenstein I have updated it to include a working example now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require(Amelia)
require(survey)
require(data.table)
require(plotrix)

a<-as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16))
b<-as.data.frame(c(1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2))
c<-as.data.frame(c(2,7,8,5,4,4,3,8,7,9,10,1,3,3,2,8))
d<-as.data.frame(c(3,9,7,4,5,5,2,10,8,10,12,2,4,4,3,7))
e<-as.data.frame(c(2500,8000,NA,4500,4500,NA,2500,NA,7400,9648,1112,1532,3487,3544,NA,7000))

impute<-cbind(a,b,c,d,e)
names(impute) <- c("X","site","var2","var3", "hh_inc") 

summary(impute)


m <- 5
a.output <- amelia(x = impute, m=m, autopri=0.5,cs="X",
               idvars=c("site","var2"),
               logs=c("hh_inc","var3"))

stats.out <- NULL
for(i in 1:m){
df2 <- data.table(a.output$imputations[[i]])
df3 <-  data.frame(dataset=i,df2[,list(std.error(hh_inc),mean(hh_inc)), by="site"])
stats.out <- rbind(stats.out, df3)
}
colnames(stats.out) <- c("dataset","site","stdError","mean")
stats.out
```

Comment: That is halfway there. But what I now need is to work out the standard error and mean for each of the sites. So under object "b" which is renamed to "site", I want to know what the standard error and mean is of "hh_inc" for when site =1 and then for when site=2. I have edited your post to show how the results can be combined.

Comment: Also I apologise, in my code I gave originally in my initial question, there was a data frame called "base_data" which I then renamed "imputations" in my example for some reason. Sorry for confusing there.

Comment: @TimothyAlston: Sorry forgot about that piece.  I think the edit takes care of it.

Comment: I have got this working perfectly for my actual data. Thank you! Can't award the bounty yet, but will in 20 hours.

Comment: +1 too. But the rbind inside a for loop is an R sin, though. As m increases that may bite.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question or the structure of your data (specifically the importance of whether the data is imputed or not) but here's how I've done some summary stats by group.

```
require(data.table)
require(plotrix)

# create some data
df1 <- data.frame(id=seq(1,50,1), wealth = runif(50)*1000)
df1$cutter <- cut(df1$wealth, 5, labels=FALSE)
head(df1)
# put the data into a data.table to speed things up  
df2 <- as.data.table(df1)
head(df2)

grp1StdErr <- df2[,std.error(wealth), by="cutter"]
grp1Mean <- df2[,mean(wealth), by="cutter"]
```

Hope this helps.

Or, in one grouping step :

```
df2[,list(std.error(wealth),mean(wealth)), by=cut(wealth,5,labels=FALSE)]
```

Comment: The importance of the imputed data is that the missing values in my data frame are not replaced as such, rather the imputed values remain in an 'amelia' type object. So running your code above would ignore the imputed values which are sitting in the amelia type object (a.output in my example above), which can cause bias. So I need code which allows for the these imputed values to also be taken into account and reflect the uncertainty surrounding the imputed values. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @TimothyAlston: Any chance of you posting a working example?  Specifically how are you getting the results from the Amelia object?

Comment: @Matthew Dowle: double check your code.  When I run it I get: 

> df2[,.(std.error(wealth),mean(wealth)), by=cut(wealth,5,labels=FALSE)]
Error in `[.data.table`(df2, , .(std.error(wealth), mean(wealth)), by = cut(wealth,  : 
  could not find function "."

Comment: Oops, running ahead of myself. Fixed.

Comment: @screechOwl busy working on getting a working example made up. Will hopefully post it shortly (Amelia seems to need largeish data sets, so hard to make one up that is large enough).

Comment: @MatthewDowle I have edited my original question to give an example of data and imputations to show what I am trying to do. Hopefully it makes sense.